# The error of user-defined class in object-c

Tags: objective-c

This is `Circle.h`:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef enum{
    KCircle,
    KRectangle
}ShapeType;

typedef enum{
    KRedColor,
    KGreenColor,
    KBlueColor
}ShapeColor;

typedef struct{
    int x, y, width, height;
}ShapeRect;


typedef struct{
    ShapeType type;
    ShapeColor fillColor;
    ShapeRect bounds;
}Shape;

@interface Circle : NSObject{
    ShapeColor mColor;
    ShapeRect mBound;
}

-(void) setBound: (ShapeRect) bound;
-(void) setFillColor: (ShapeColor) color;
-(void) draw;
@end
```

This is `Circle.m`

```
#import "Circle.h"

@implementation Circle

-(void) setBound:(ShapeRect)bound{
    mBound = bound;
}

-(void)setFillColor:(ShapeColor)color{
    mColor = color;
}

-(NSString*) colorName: (ShapeColor)color{
    switch (color) {
        case KGreenColor:
            return @"Green";
            break;
        case KRedColor:
            return @"Red";
            break;
        case KBlueColor:
            return @"Blue";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

-(void) draw
{
    NSLog(@"drawing a circle (%d %d %d %d) in %@",
          mBound.x, mBound.y, mBound.width, mBound.height, colorName(mColor));
}

@end
```

when i compile the file, i meet this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_colorName", referenced from:
  -[Circle draw] in Circle.o
 (maybe you meant: _colorName1)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: you are right, could you tell me why? i have removed the function `colorName` in other file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(NSString*) colorName: (ShapeColor)color;
```

is an Objective-C *method* and not a *function*, so you have to use the correct syntax for calling methods. Replace

```
colorName(mColor)
```

by

```
[self colorName:mColor]
```

Comment: yeah, thank you. the funtion `colorName` is a private method of class Circle, so i think that i can call `colorName` like this `colorName(mColor)`

Comment: @BlackMamba There is only one syntax for calling methods in Objective-C and Objective-C does not have private methods...  you should revisit an Objective-C tutorial.